# How can I get the CAD model and dimensions for the connector support of a space launcher?

Tags: esa, structural-design

[image: connector support]

I am a university student and want to do topology optimisation and additive manufacturing research for this component but cannot seem to find the accurate dimensions for it. I would be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: I don't expect you'll be able to find that information: Rocket manufacturers generally don't publish CAD models. They only publish specifications for the adapter between the spacecraft and the rocket, even those tend to describe the mating surface only, not the metalwork below it.